# How to open Samsung's Settings Page?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

Can anyone help me with opening Samsung phone's settings? Tried the following code but it's not working

CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.sm", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"));
        try {
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Smart manager not installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Amazing! that did work but more specifically i want to open in SETTING=>SMART MANAGER=> PERFORMANCE ENHANCER

Comment: Here is the list of supported action using Intent. Have a look at it
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: Thanks but the settings I want is not listed in that

Comment: exactly, you can't open specific device's setting menu.

Comment: All the other OEM's settings i can open only Samsung I Can't

Comment: Yes, Samsung made custom ROM so many functionality they've added on their own and also we shouldn't write code device specific. Hope you get it.